# If $|a| \leq |b|$, is $|a-k| \leq |b-k|?$

Tags: inequality

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are two numbers such that $|a| \leq |b|$. Let $k \geq 0$. Is it necessarily true that
$$|a-k| \leq |b-k|?$$

The triangle inequality doesn't help..

Answer (score 2):

It is not true in general. Take for example $a = -1$, $b = 2$, $k=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$|a-k| \leq |b-k|$ is true when $k$ is closer to $a$ than it is to $b$, i.e. the $a$-side of the midpoint, so

- when $k \le \dfrac{a+b}{2}$ and $a \le b$
- or when $k \ge \dfrac{a+b}{2}$ and $a \ge b$

This means counter-examples will be all cases where these are not true while $|a| \le |b|$, such as $a=1, k=8, b=9$

Answer (score 1):

*Counter-example*: take $k=b$. Is $|a-b|\le |0|\;$ true in general?